# Arch Linux: make - no such file or directory

Tags: linux, build, compilation, archlinux

I have a problem by compiling a driver (WLAN-dongle Edimax ac600).

I´m using an Archlinux on my raspberry-pi and want to install my dongle for 5Ghz. During comiling the driver I get this message. I tried to install the linux-headers without success. (in other threads it will be a solution)

Here is my output of `make`:

```
[root@raspberry_pi_1 rtl8812AU]# make make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE= -C
/lib/modules/4.9.43-1-ARCH/build M=/root/rtl8812AU  modules make[1]:
 *** /lib/modules/4.9.43-1-ARCH/build: No such file or directory.  Stop. make: *** [Makefile:1576: modules] Error 2
```

I found out that my pi has a two-arch...-directories:

```
4.9.43-1-ARCH/
4.9.51-1-ARCH/
```

Only the second one has the build directory...

How can I fix the problem?!

thanks a lot,
a Linux noob...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Reputation is too low to post comment]

Use uname -r to make sure which version of the kernel you use.

If it's `4.9.43` : you have newer version of the kernel and this confuse your installer. You should reboot on the 51 one

If it's `4.9.51` : You messed up your installation step and are trying to compile for an old target. You should review the compilation process and change every mention of the `4.9.43` to `4.9.51` since it's the version you use.

If you upgrade your kernel, you may have to rebuild the thing again (You may like to have script in the future ;) ) with the new kernel version.

Comment: I startet only with `make` and my post above shows the output. (question edited)

Comment: You should check your kernel version with `uname -r`
There is a chance you are trying to compile an old version that was removed from your system.

Comment: It´s 4.9.43! How can I restart the RaspberryPi with 4.9.51 ??

Comment: in theorie, you should have 4.9.51 in grub at the boot time. if not, you could try to update your system with pacman and run with the last kernel you got.
Anyway, you could also run all the build process you have done replacing 4.9.51 by the 43 version to downgrade your system (not recommanded, but you may not run critical infrastructure so...)

Comment: Thank you so much! Maybe the first update failed. The second try (pacman -Syu) left the folder with the new version of the kernel. After that the built process was successful.